# The POM for jxgrabkey:jxgrabkey:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: java, maven, selenium, dependencies

please help me on this:
Got following dependency error while exceuting maven:

Failed to execute goal on project com.automation.selenium: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.automation:com.automation.selenium:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find jxgrabkey:jxgrabkey:jar:1.0

In pom.xml, ihave added the below details:

```
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jxgrabkey/jxgrabkey -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jxgrabkey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jxgrabkey</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: It means you are trying to get the dependency which is no longer available in the repository

Answer (score 2):

I found the jar which you needed. You will have to download this and have to add it in the class path. As you don't have the option to use maven for this jar. May be they have deleted from the repository.

https://labs.consol.de/maven/repository/jxgrabkey/jxgrabkey/1.0/

Thanks You.

Comment: Hi.. But i have already added this jar in my repository(.m2/repository/jxgrabkey/jxgrabkey/1.0).

Answer (score 0):

For the above case, it is strange to say but added the dependency "jxgrabkey" on to the master maven project and re-build the project. Later again removed the dependency from the maven project, it cleared all errors.

Strange but it worked for me

Regards,
Santosh